# How to convert two integers in one using C#?

Tags: c#

How to convert two integers in one using C#? Without using a string. like

```
int health = 100;
    int damageTaken = 50;
    bool alive= true;
    if (alive == true){
    Debug.Log ("You are alive!" + ????(what goes here? I cant put health -
    damageTaken + "Hitpoints");                                                          .       
    }
```

`
Not using a string.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more clear what you are actually looking for?

Comment: I've answered your question below. As you're a new user, I'd just like to point out that Google is often a good source of answers for simple problems such as this, and often even complicated problems. Most of the time you will find links to existing StackOverflow posts which answer your exact question.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot concatenate an int with an int.**

You need to do: `Debug.Log("You are alive! " + (health-damageTaken) + " Hitpoints.");`

This way we "combine" the two integers into an answer.

This is equivalent as writing this:

```
int health = 100;
int damageTaken = 50;
int hitpoints = health - damageTaken;
Debug.Log("You are alive! " + hitpoints + " Hitpoints.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#6 or 7, then string interpolation is the way to go.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

```
 int health = 100;
 int damageTaken = 50;
 bool alive = true;
 if (alive == true)
 {
     Debug.Log($"You are alive! {health-damageTaken} HitPoints");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Old way use string.Format

```
Debug.Log (string.Format("You are alive! {0} Hitpoints",health-damageTaken));
```

New way, use '$' infront of string:

```
Debug.Log ($"You are alive! {health-damageTaken} Hitpoints");
```

When compiled they are the same

Answer (score 0):

```
int health = 100;
int damageTaken = 50;
int remainingHealth = health - damageTaken;
bool alive = remainingHealth > 0;
if (alive) 
{
    Debug.Log ($"You are alive! {remainingHealth} Hitpoints");                                                        
}
```

For maths in C# you can do: +, -, /, * for add, subtract, divide, and multiply respectively.

You also have % which gives you the remainder (e.g. 3 % 2 returns 1).

For powers, use Math.Pow(,) - for example, Math.Pow(2, 4) gives you the result of 2^4 (16)